# How to open a second input box which is followed by another input box Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

Very newbie question, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Upon selection of cell ("A501") I want to prompt the user to enter a number. I then want to enter that user-input number into cell ("Y501"). After that number has been provided I want a second input box ("Enter Cubic:") to appear, whose value would be automatically placed in cell ("Z501").This is the code that I have on my sheet2, which currently doesn't work

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call RunallMacros
End Sub

Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim C As Range

    For Each C In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Z501")
        If Selection.Count = 1 Then
            If Not Intersect(target, Range("a501")) Is Nothing Then
                Carton = InputBox("Enter Carton Quantity")
                Range("Y501").value = Carton
                If C.value > 0 Then
                    Cubic = InputBox("Enter Cubic")
                    Range("Z501").value = Cubic
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: not possible using `inputbox`, `userform` would be the answer

Comment: I've updated & checked my answer to make sure it works as you need it to and it appears it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try restricting the `Carton` InputBox to numbers only (see [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx) for list of restriction codes), then check `Carton` instead of `C.Value`

```
Dim Carton As Integer
Carton = Application.InputBox("Enter Carton Quantity", Type:=1)
Range("Y501").Value = Carton
If Carton > 0 Then
    Dim Cubic As Integer
    Cubic = Application.InputBox("Enter Cubic", Type:=1)
    Range("Z501").Value = Cubic
End If
```